# unwanted line under a tabbar indicator

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm creating a android app in flutter.

```
Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
              child: Container(
                height: 38,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 8, 12, 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  border: Border.all(color: AppColor.blueColor, width: 2),
                ),
                child: TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: AppColor.pinkColor,
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: AppColor.pinkColor),

                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,

                  indicatorWeight: 0,

                  // isScrollable: true,
                  splashBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
                  controller: _tabController, // Use the TabController.
                  automaticIndicatorColorAdjustment: true,
                  overlayColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(AppColor.pinkColor),
                  // physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  //
                  // unselectedLabelColor: AppColor.greyColor,
                  unselectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                  labelColor: AppColor.blackColor,
                  labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Edit Profile',
                    ),
                    Tab(text: 'Preview Profile'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
```

i have tried every possible solution according to me.
in this code:

this code suppose to create a toggle tabbbar to switch b/w screens the finctionality is working fine but ther is a annoying straignt line under the indicator tab, which i'm unable to remove.

stuck with this for for about a day now

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem. you have to use dividerColor

> TabBar(
> dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
> // ...
> )

Answer (score 0):

```
TabBar(
  controller: controller,
  indicator: const BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide.none),
  ),
  labelColor: Colors.amber,
  tabs: const [
    Tab(child: Text('A')),
    Tab(child: Text('B')),
    Tab(child: Text('C')),
  ],
 ),
)
```

Add property **indicator:** and set **border: Border(bottom: BorderSide.none)** to remove line under tabbar.

Hopefully can help.

---

***-Nannn***